# Excel Pivot table show column A value associated with MAX of column B

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

So I have the following data:

```
Group      Name      Units Ordered
G1         Amy       52
G1         Marc      108
G1         Antony    76
G2         James     52
G2         Hal       12
```

What I'd like to do, using a pivot table, is format the result like this:

```
Group    Best Customer
G1       Marc
G2       James
```

Where best customer is the Name with the most Units Ordered. I've been playing with the pivot table functions for some time now and finding the max value(108, 52) is easy, but I can find a resource that explains how to display an associated column for the value you find.

Comment: Is using a Pivot table strictly necessary? The obvious way to get your desired output from input as shown would be a formula.

Comment: Well, I was already constructing a pivot table for a bunch of other requirements for this table, and figured there should be a way to orient the data this way using the same technology. Though I suppose precreating a column with a formula would be acceptable